# Matrix to count table?

Tags: r

From my matrix which looks like:

```
structure(list(1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 2, 1.5, 1.5, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5, 
15, 15, 1.5, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 1.5, 5, 15, 15, 1.5, 15, 
15, 15, 15, 15, 1), .Dim = c(10L, 3L), .Dimnames = list(c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"), NULL))
```

I want to get a table of counts of each level. Something like:

```
column level counts
1      1.5    5
1      2      1
2      1.5    2
2      5      1
2      15     7
3      1      1
3      1.5    1
3      5      1
3      15     7
```

How can I do that?

I'm not sure about the structure names I am after, which probably explains why I'm unsuccessful in finding what I want. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm taking the liberty of answering my own question. It is entirely based on @epi99's answer, and @Pradeep's comments got me to understand there was something weird with my data. It's probably far from being the most efficient but I think it's easier to understand for R rookies like me.

It makes use of the `reshape2` and `dplyr` packages. Install them if that's not already done:

```
install.packages ("reshape2")
install.packages ("dplyr")
```

Then:

```
# Import the libraries
library (reshape2) 
library (dplyr) 

# Import the sample data
test_map <- structure(list(1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 2, 1.5, 1.5, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5, 
           15, 15, 1.5, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 1.5, 5, 15, 15, 1.5, 15, 
           15, 15, 15, 15, 1), .Dim = c(10L, 3L), .Dimnames = list(c("1", 
           "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"), NULL))

# test_map is a matrix of lists, which does not work well.
# I'm first transforming it into a matrix where each column is numerics. 
# (that's probably not necessary in most cases)
testmap2 <- apply (test_map, 2, as.numeric)

# then melt (reshape2), group_by and count (dplyr)
test_melted <- melt (testmap2, na.rm = TRUE)
test_grouped <- group_by (melted, Var2, value)
test_counted <- count (grouped)
```

Result:

```
> test_counted

Source: local data frame [9 x 3]
Groups: Var2 [?]

   Var2 value     n
  <int> <dbl> <int>
1     1   1.5     5
2     1   2.0     1
3     2   1.5     2
4     2   5.0     1
5     2  15.0     7
6     3   1.0     1
7     3   1.5     1
8     3   5.0     1
9     3  15.0     7
```

Answer (score 2):

This uses `dplyr` to group and `melt` from `resshape2` convert from a wide column format to a to all format. This uses data frames - if you provide your data using  `dput` in future it is easrier use the exact structure you have.

```
m <- read.table(text="
[,1] [,2] [,3]
1  1.5  5    5   
2  1.5  15   15  
3  1.5  15   15  
4  2    1.5  1.5 
5  1.5  15   15  
6  1.5  15   15  
7  NA   15   15  
8  NA   15   15  
9  NA   15   15  
10 NA   1.5  1 
", header=TRUE) 

library(reshape2)
library(dplyr)

melt(m, na.rm = TRUE) %>%
  group_by(variable, value) %>%
  summarize(n = n())

#   variable value     n
#   <fctr> <dbl> <int>
# 1    X..1.   1.5     5
# 2    X..1.   2.0     1
# 3    X..2.   1.5     2
# 4    X..2.   5.0     1
# 5    X..2.  15.0     7
# 6    X..3.   1.0     1
# 7    X..3.   1.5     1
# 8    X..3.   5.0     1
# 9    X..3.  15.0     7
```

Comment: You could replace `summarize(n=n())` by just `count` from dplyr.

Comment: I'm sorry I cannot make your solution work, I'm not sure why.  It is returning `Error in group_by_(.data, .dots = lazyeval::lazy_dots(...), add = add) : object 'variable' not found`. I feel like the reason why it works in your case might be the way you import the data, but I'm not sure how to show a sample of my data in my question in a different way.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
```

**Edit**: After OP has given the structure, I have changed the code.

```
mtable <- apply(test_map,2,unlist)
mtable <- data.table(mtable,seq=1:nrow(m)) ##converting to data.table with a dummy key to melt
names(mtable) = c('a','b','c','seq') ##changing names

mfnew <- melt(mtable, id=('seq'))[,2:3,with=T] ##meting the data basis the dummy key so that the data could be gathered in one column
mfnew
setkeyv(mfnew,c("variable","value")) ##optional

final <- mfnew[,list(cnt=.N),by=list(variable,value)][,2:3,with=T]
final
final[!is.na(final$value),]**Output:**

    > final[!is.na(final$value),]
   value cnt
1:   1.5   5
2:   2.0   1
3:   1.5   2
4:   5.0   1
5:  15.0   7
6:   1.0   1
7:   1.5   1
8:   5.0   1
9:  15.0   7
```

Comment: I'm sorry it seems like my data might be slightly different. I'm getting `Error in setkeyv(mfnew, c("variable", "value")) : Column 'value' is type 'list' which is not supported as a key column type, currently`. Any idea what I could do?

Comment: Here it is 
`List of 30
 $ : num 1.5
 $ : num 1.5
 $ : num 1.5
 $ : num 2
 $ : num 1.5
 $ : num 1.5
 $ : logi NA
 $ : logi NA
 $ : logi NA
 $ : logi NA
 $ : num 5
 $ : num 15
 $ : num 15
 $ : num 1.5
 $ : num 15
 $ : num 15
 $ : num 15
 $ : num 15
 $ : num 15
 $ : num 1.5
 $ : num 5
 $ : num 15
 $ : num 15
 $ : num 1.5
 $ : num 15
 $ : num 15
 $ : num 15
 $ : num 15
 $ : num 15
 $ : num 1
 - attr(*, "dim")= int [1:2] 10 3
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : chr [1:10] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
  ..$ : NULL`

Comment: I think my matrix contains lists, hence the problems... Any way I can simplify that to a more "normal" matrix?

Comment: @Krollibrius , Use mytable <- data.table( do.call("cbind",tlist)) where tlist is your list name, then run again the entire command.

Comment: @Krollibrius, In case you are still struggling , please do a `dput(list_name)` and save the result and add that in the question above. In that way anyone can copy paste your structure entirely and solution would be more robust

Comment: Thanks, that's indeed a much better way to share a sample of my data! As to the other comment, `data.table( do.call("cbind",tlist))` is putting all my matrix in one row, I don't think this is what we are after...